# should I put default declaration on the same stylesheet with the media queries stylesheet?

Tags: css, media-queries

I put my default declaration in `style.css` and then I put all media queries in different sytlesheet called `enhanced.css`.

For example, I put a code in `style.css` something like this:

`.box{height: 600px;}`

and then I put a css code in `enhanced.css` so the box's height will decrease when it is on a smaller screen.

`@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
   .box{height:300px;}
}`

But unfortunately it didn't work in small screen. It always follow styles from `style.css`. My question is, can I do something like above? To put default declaration on different sylesheet, or should I put default declaration **on the same stylesheet** with the media queries stylesheet ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including `style.css` *after* `enhanced.css` ?

Comment: You can put them on different stylesheets (the order of including them has an influence).

Comment: yes, I did that...is that a matter?

Comment: @Itay can you explain to me? Wow I never put attention on the order of my stylesheets!

Comment: Yeah. Because they have the same priority level, the latest included one will overpower. [Reviewing CSS style priority level](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/)

Comment: @Itay & Adrift I can't believe this... You're right.. I change the order and it works perfectly..Thanks so much! I wish I could check your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your selectors are of equal [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) (`@media` rules don't have any specificity) - both rules are using one class selector (`.box`) and because you're loading `.style.css` after `enhanced.css` the former takes precedence. You need to increase the specificity of your `@media` rule if you want to include it before your regular `.box` rule - e.g.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body .box {
        height: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: oh wow...thanks you for your answer..but your comment save me! It's all about ORDER! I can't believe this

Comment: @ElaYudhanira : If that's the answer you were looking for, you should accept it (with the green "V" button)

Comment: The counter-intuitive thing here is that being inside a `@media` rule does not make a declaration more specific in CSS terms (even though it is intuitively more specific). CSS just has specificity rules defined in terms of selectors only, so indeed we may need to modify selectors just to make a media-dependent rule override a normal rule.